# Export/Import NSImage as ICO

Tags: cocoa, icons, save, nsimage

I would like to save and read an ICO file. It doesnt matter if its NSImage or NSBitmapImageRep or anything. It just needs to be done. How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out for myself. Here is my code:

```
NSImage *o = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(
                                                             (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath], 
                                                             (CFStringRef)@"com.microsoft.ico", 
                                                             o.representations.count,
                                                             NULL);
for (NSBitmapImageRep *rep in o.representations) {
    CGImageRef ref = rep.CGImage;
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, 
                               ref, 
                               NULL);
}


CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
```

Comment: After a while of using the above solution, i decided I needed more features, specifically custom sizes. So i wrote a class myself that supports any size between 0 and 256.
http://github.com/alexzielenski/ICOFamily